# re to find longest matching postfix of two strings

Tags: python, regex, string-matching, longest-substring

I have two strings like:

```
a = '54515923333558964'
b = '48596478923333558964'
```

Now the longest postfix match is

```
c = '923333558964'
```

what will be a solution using re?

Here is a solution I found for prefix match:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(?P<mt>\S*)\S*\s+(?P=mt)")
a = '923333221486456'
b = '923333221486234567'
c = pattern.match(a + ' ' + b).group('mt')
```

Comment: Why would you want to use `re` for that?

Comment: Also: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @MartijnPieters nothing special any solution other then loop is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this variation of the regex pattern:

```
\S*?(?P<mt>\S*)\s+\S*(?P=mt)$
```

EDIT.
Note, however, that this may require O(*n*<sup>3</sup>) time with some inputs. Try e.g.

```
a = 1000 * 'a'
b = 1000 * 'a' + 'b'
```

This takes one second to process on my system.

Answer (score 6):

Try the [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher):

```
import difflib
a = '54515923333558964'
b = '48596478923333558964'

s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
m = s.find_longest_match(0, len(a), 0, len(b))
print a[m.a:m.a+m.size]
```

Comment: @eumiro.. Can you please explain this method you have used??

Comment: @RohitJain see the linked documentation